# Appropriate substitute for Montserrat italic

Tags: fonts

I'm looking for an appropriate (free) substitute for Montserrat italic. Now I'm using Noto Sans italic, but it doesn't look really good:

[image]

Comment: While there is no italic of Monserrat, it's worth noting that more weight variations are available via github than with google fonts' current offering https://github.com/JulietaUla/Montserrat

Answer (score 1):

How about Raleway Medium Italic?

[image: using Montserrat with Raleway Medium Italic as an italics replacement]

Answer (score 0):

maybe pt sans but i found montserrat really thicker than other fonts. pt sans bold italic maybe

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE. Please make your answer more complete by adding screenshots of the fonts so we don't have to go searching around the web. We don't want one-line answers, add some more details why you think your font is a match.